# how to sum a list of max values group by

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I'm trying to `sum` the `max` values of a column named `value1` grouped by sensor id value so I want the last greater value from each sensor id.

Using this code I get a column with rows with the max results for each sensor. But I dont know how to sum this values.

```
select max(value1) from `digiwork_esp-data`.SensorData group by sensor
```

I need to sum this individual values of the result into a total. I tried this, but it is returning a big number (not correct):

```
select sum(value1) 
from `digiwork_esp-data`.SensorData
where value1 = any (SELECT max(value1) FROM `digiwork_esp-data`.SensorData group by sensor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly `sum` the result of the `subquery`.

```
select sum(t1.val) from
    (select max(value1) val FROM digiwork_esp-data.SensorData group by sensor) t1
```

Comment: thanks so much Metal.. soooo much im new to this.... your code worked perfect! i just had to add the `` to the database like this select sum(t1.val) from (select max(value1) val FROM ` digiwork_esp-data `.SensorData group by sensor) t1 but with no spaces... thanks so much i tried to find in internet this solution for hours ! have a great week METAL! just a question for the sake of learning and leave this knowledge for whoever find this post... how is it called the technic used? agregation? join?